# Getting information from a closed excel workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract information from a closed workbook using excel VBA, more specifically, the sum of a range of numbers in the closed excel workbook into my current excel workbook.

I have tried the following codes below:
I want to find the sum of values from Z8 to the last Z cell in the column.

```
Range("D4").Formula = "Sum('I:\Outgoing\Money Outgoing\'!$Z8:$Z)"
```

```
Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open("I:\Outgoing\Money Outgoing.xlsx\")
Range("Z7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Z8:Z10000)"
Range("D4").Value = GetInfoFromClosedFile(a, f, d, "Z6")
```

I do not wish to open the closed workbook
The excel file is Money Outgoing.xlsx
There is only 1 tab in the file. Tab name is Layout 1

Comment: I would avoid linking workbooks like this. Is `I:` a mapped network drive? What if someone renames it `Money Outgoing 2019-2020.xlsx`? You could probably try `Sheet1.Range("D4").Formula = "=Sum('[I:\Outgoing\Money Outgoing.xlsx]Layout 1'!$Z8:$Z10000)"`. See [avoid Select and Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513), too. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, to avoid reference to Z10000 but to the last z cell, is it $Z8:$Z ?

Comment: No, you can't do that without opening the file AFAIK. `$Z8:$Z` is a syntax error as far as Excel is concerned.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu! that helped a lot. If possible could you take a look at my other post if you have time?

Answer (score 0):

Without opening the workbook, you can use below code.
Modify this with your needs.

```
Sub ExecuteMacroForClosedWorkbook()

Dim FldrName As String
Dim FlName As String
Dim WrkshtName As String
Dim ExecuteStringVariable As String

ExecuteStringVariable = "'" & FldrName & "\" & "[" & FlName & "]" & WrkshtName & "'!R"

ActiveCell.value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(ExecuteStringVariable & 1 & "C1") 'Execute A1 Cell and Transfer Value to Your ActiveCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mehmet, I have another question.